# Как сделать пересылку из одного бота в другой?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, telegram

Ребят, подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать чтобы пользователь в одном боте два раза выбирал из предоставленных кнопок одну, бот запоминал его два ответа, отправлял эти данные в одном сообщении другому боту, который уже будет отправлять выбранные ответы админу (другому пользователю). Я пишу бота на питоне.
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это можно реализовать только через прослойку
**USER -> BOT_1 -> BOT_USER -> BOT_2 -> ADMIN**

USER делает 2 раза выбор, далее BOT_1 отправляет этот выбор на BOT_USER, он в свою очередь пересылает это BOT_2, а вот BOT_2 отправляет это ADMIN.

Вам необходимо сделать 1 юзер бота, и 2 обычных бота.
Главный бот передаёт сообщение, юзер боту, а юзер бот передаёт второму, что-бы тот в свою очередь передал это админу.
К сожалению нет возможности отправки сообщения из бота к боту.

Для реализации юзер бота вам понадобиться telethon библиотека.

*Ответ предоставляю строго из вашего описания, есть и более изящные способы решения этой задачи, только с другим функционалом.*